# How to find out which .c file contains the .c functions of R internals, on Windows?

Tags: r, windows, function, internals

I want to view the source code of R's `match.call` function. As it is an internal function, I downloaded the R source code, went to ./src/main/names.c and looked for `match.call` there.

Thus, I found out that the corresponding .c function is called `do_matchcall`. Ok, but how can I find out which of the dozens of .c files in ./src/main/ contains the function `do_matchcall`?

Btw I'm using a Windows machine, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: +1 for reasons I ditched Windows. `../R-2.15.2/src> grep do_matchcall */*` returns `main/unique.c` (among others).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a Windows user, here are a couple of options. The first one is preferable, but the second one is  OK for occasional use:

- Download [**grepwin**](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html), which will allow you to search Windows directories using the powerful `grep` command that both Joshua and Gavin have mentioned. It (or some equivalent) is **indispensable** if you'll be doing much poking around in program source directories.
- Use the search bar at [this site](http://fossies.org/dox/R-2.15.2/index.html) to search the R source directory for the definition of `do_matchcall`. Clicking on the result it returns will tell you that `do_matchcall` is "[defined] at line 1193 of file unique.c", and will provide a hyperlink to the code in unique.c.

Like I said, though, you'll ultimately be much happier if you equip your Windows box with *some* implementation of `grep`.

Comment: Wow, thanks, the site you linked is awesome. Perfect for someone who only occasionally wants to look up a single R internal.

Comment: @WolfgangPößnecker -- Glad that helps. Do be aware that the link will break when R is next updated. To make it work then, just edit the "version part" of http://fossies.org/dox/R-2.15.2/index.html from "R-2.15.2" to whatever the current version is.

Comment: @WolfgangPößnecker: [searching for `do_matchcall` on rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&q=do_matchcall&newwindow=1&cof=FORID%3A11) is another alternative, and [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/) is handy in general.

Comment: Google magic as an option too `site:https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/ do_matchcall`

Answer (score 10):

I know this has been asked a long time ago, but since it's still relevant, I thought I'd add some resources people can use to find the proper R source files.

1. First, with **pryr** you can use the `show_c_source` function which will search on GitHub the relevant piece of code in the C source files.

   ```
   body(match.call)

   # .Internal(match.call(definition, call, expand.dots))

   pryr::show_c_source(.Internal(match.call(definition, call, expand.dots)))
   ```

   Which takes you to [this page](https://github.com/search?q=SEXP%20attribute_hidden%20do_matchcall%20repo:wch/r-source&type=Code), showing that `unique.c` contains the function [do_matchcall](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ec8db8be924cf4ffd49438cbca38b876c7931863/src/main/unique.c#L1261).
2. I've put together this [tab delimited file](https://gist.github.com/dcomtois/261ff939d1a1b27525f1), building on the `names.c` file and using *find-in-files* to determine the location of the source code. There are some functions that have platform-specific files, and a handful of others for which there is more than one file with relevant source code. But for the rest the mapping is pretty well established, at least for the current version (3.1.2).

Comment: The tab delimited file in the above answer is wonderfully helpful!  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 6):

Uwe Ligges wrote an "R Help Desk" article on this very topic in [R News (2006, 6(4):43-45)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf).

Once you've identified the actual C function that is used, then use your filesystem search tools to search for the function name in the relevant source folder; in this case `./src/main/`, e.g. on Linux

```
$ grep -r -H "do_matchcall" ./src/main/
./src/main/.svn/text-base/names.c.svn-base:{"match.call",   do_matchcall,   0,  11, 3,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
./src/main/.svn/text-base/unique.c.svn-base:SEXP attribute_hidden do_matchcall(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
./src/main/unique.c:SEXP attribute_hidden do_matchcall(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
./src/main/names.c:{"match.call",   do_matchcall,   0,  11, 3,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
```

indicating that `unique.c` is the place to look in this case.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way (other than invoking a system call to the terminal) to identify from within R which source file contains the C code for a given function in R - well, not without rewriting `grep` or `find` or similar using R code :-)

Comment: I'll second your recommendation of Uwe Ligges' article. It's essential reading for R users.

Comment: Thanks for your helpfull answer. However, I already knew the referenced article. But the lines "If the filename is not obvious, then it can be found by
simply ‘grep’ping for the string in R’s $R_HOME/src/" never made sense to me as I never used Linux. The answer by Josh O'Brien also indirectly shows that 'grep'ing is not thaaaat 'simple' or 'natural' for a windows user.

Comment: As a non-Windows user, I was assuming that you would know how to search for strings in files on your OS. Really that is your question and you might get better help if you wrote that as a Q (but not on [so] as it is not a programming issue - SuperUser might be OK) instead of directing this at the [tag:r] tag people.

Comment: Well, while you are obviously right, I simply couldn't know that my question was referring to a Windows-specific utility when I posted it. I was thinking that some R-specific function or utility or trick existed to solve my problem. Before your answers, I didn't realize that my question was ill-posed.

Comment: @WolfgangPößnecker I don't think your question is necessarily ill-posed. I was just pointing out that I had made certain assumptions when answering. The real answer to your question is that there isn't an R utility of similar that will give you what you want. I perhaps should have said that too... And this often happens - the real question *evolves* from the "discussion" or answers you are provided with here on [so].

Answer (score 1):

Don't download a utility for a one time file content search.  You can use findstr.  It isn't suitable for a full file system search, but I think it's perfect for what you are trying to do.

1. run the command shell

**cmd**

2. go to the directory  (if you are not sure what the path is, find it in explorer than view the full path by clicking in the address bar)  You can copy/paste that directory.
   If the path is C:\Users\jsmith\documents\projects\happy\src\main

**cd C:\Users\jsmith\documents\projects\happy\src\main**

3. use findstr

**findstr do_matchcall**

if you want to search sub directories

**findstr /s do_matchcall**

if only want to know the filename

**findstr /m do_matchcall**

if you want to send the results to another file

**findstr /s /m do__matchcall >searchresult.txt**

if you want the line numbers

**findstr /n do_matchcall**

Findstr also supports regular expressions.  To see all the options

**findstr /?**

Comment: This probably doesn't apply to your specific question, but for case-insensitive search use /i

findstr /i do_matchcall