# looking for the source of R's rank function

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to see the source code of R .Internal or .Primitive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function)

I'm searching for the C source used to compute R's `rank` function

I've looked in the [`R/src/main/`](http://fossies.org/dox/R-2.15.2/cov_8c_source.html) directory and i can't find it. Does anyone know where 
i can find the source code for what R calls when i use R's internal rank function? e.g. what is called when one does `.Internal(rank(x,"average"))`.

Alternatively, i would like to ensure that the efficient way to get the 
rank vector corresponding to a vector of floats is to first sort them.

Comment: Did you try just typing `rank` at the console?

Comment: yes, it calls .Internal(rank(x,"average")), hence my question.

Comment: @user189035, sorry! Reading to quickly...

Answer (score 5):

It is in `/src/main/sort.c`, about 90% of the way down the file:

```
/* FUNCTION: rank(x, length, ties.method) */
SEXP attribute_hidden do_rank(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho)
{
```

In future, you can search through the sources using a tool like `find` or `grep` as supplied with your OS to locate these things (or likely places to look).

See also, Uwe Ligge's article in R News on how to go about searching for things in R's sources: Uwe Ligges. R Help Desk: [Accessing the sources](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf). R News, 6(4):43-45, October 2006