# adding as integers instead of list elements in R

Tags: r

adding as integers instead of list elements in R

I am getting

```
> total = 0
> for (qty in a[5]){
+ total = total + as.numeric(unlist(qty))
+ print(total)
+ }
 [1] 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400
```

what i really want is :

```
> total = 0
> for (qty in a[5]){
+ total = total + as.numeric(unlist(qty))
+ print(total)
+ }
 [1] 400 800 1200 1600 2000 2400 2800 3200 3600 4000
```

refine: a little bit more to a more specific scenario,

```
price buy_sell  qty
100        B  100
100        B  200
90        S  300
100        S  400
```

I want to make a forth column

```
price buy_sell  qty net
100        B  100   10000
100        B  200   30000
90        S  300    3000
100        S  400   -37000
```

Comment: What is `a[5]`? (Best would be to post the result of `dput(a[5])`)

Comment: i think you want cumsum

Comment: a5 is a list of integers:

> a[5]
   qty
1  412
2  400
3  432
4  400
5  453
6  400
7  392
8  400
9  302
10 400

Comment: hi danielho, can you please copy the `dput` statement @DavidRobinson mentioned and paste the output into your question above

Comment: > dput (a[5])
structure(list(qty = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L)), .Names = "qty", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

Comment: @danielho, sorry, but your edit makes no sense relative to your original question.

Comment: yes you are right Ricardo, I asked the wrong question as I was trying to split the problem up.

Comment: You're more than welcomed to add a new question.  Why not put your question back to how it was and ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

Note that if `a` is a list, you want to use double brackets.  Otherwise you are getting back a list of size one, where the first element has the values you are looking for

Try:

```
 total <- cumsum(a[[5]])
```

---

```
a <- list()
a[[5]] <- rep(400, 10)

cumsum(a[[5]])
#  [1]  400  800 1200 1600 2000 2400 2800 3200 3600 4000
```

Compare:

```
 a[5]
 a[[5]]
 a[5][[1]]
```

Comment: You might be able to add more characters by explaining the difference between `[` and `[[` for lists, which is probably why the OP's loop isn't working the way they expect. :)

Comment: @Joran hahaha, i was typing just that as you wrote your comment ;)

Comment: @Joran, however, it could be that `a` is *not* a list, or `as.numeric(a[5])` would throw an error

Comment: is there anyway to look at the source of cumsum? i want to modify it a little

Comment: Absolutely!  Take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function/14035586#14035586