# Faster R: Why rowSums in R is so fast?

Tags: r

I was curious about computation time in R especially while dealing with matrix or data frame. Let's notice the following example:

```
    slowFun = function() {
      mat = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000 * 10), 10000, 10))
      mat[, (ncol(mat) + 1)] = NA
      for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
        mat[i,ncol(mat)] = sum(mat[i,], na.rm = T)
      }
    }

    fastFun = function() {
      mat = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000 * 10), 10000, 10))
      mat[, (ncol(mat) + 1)] = NA
      mat[,ncol(mat)] = rowSums(mat, na.rm = T)
    }


    system.time(slowFun())
    system.time(fastFun())

   > system.time(slowFun())
   user  system elapsed 
   3.614   0.219   3.837 
   > system.time(fastFun())
   user  system elapsed 
   0.012   0.001   0.013
```

rowSums was impressive. When I tried to learn all about it:

```
    rowSums
```

It does not let me see how it was coded! I see .Internal and don't know where to look about it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is in the arena of the wider topic of vectorization in R. Of which you will find many discussions around. Here's one explanation: http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html, especially part four on functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function/14035586#14035586

Comment: How to view the code for an `.Internal` function is described in the answer to [How can I view the source code for a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/271616).

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf

Comment: The reason is that the function was written in c++. 
If you are astounded by the speed of rowSums you should definitely try using Rfast's implementation (i.e. Rfast::rowsums)