# R: Further understanding on the .Internal function

Tags: r

I have read the description but i am still confuse by the role of the `.Internal` function. Because it works fine with `.Internal(body(mean))`but not with `.Internal(mean)`. I presume that this is written in c++ and is compiled, but it is possible to see the code? In what folder of the R folder is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can view the c source code with this:

```
pryr::show_c_source(.Internal(mean()))
```

From @Dominic Comtois post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function), "the `show_c_source` function will search on GitHub for the relevant piece of code in the C source files. Works for .Internal and .Primitive functions."

Comment: Thanks! but i would like to see .Internal() . Cant do that with show_c_source. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read through [this](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/R/manual/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive) source?

Comment: I just tried `pryr::show_c_source(.Internal(.Internal()))` and it seemed to work

Comment: Thanks Adam and Richard? Last follow up question :) Can it be modify?