# Chinese Character Encoding in R Studio

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, chinese-locale

I am currently working with large CSVs of Chinese medical records in R Studio but am having trouble processing Han Chinese characters. In particular,  I am able to ["view" Chinese characters in table form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLOY8.png) (i.e. using R Studio's built-in data viewer to see the entire dataset), but I am unable to [render them in outputs from code-chunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXEQt.png) of the R Markdown -- i.e. unable to "process"/"interact" with them.

I've already tried setting the system locale to Simplified Chinese via `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "chs")`, reading in the .csv with UTF-8 encoding via `read.csv('filepath/filename.csv', encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, and even changing the OS system language (Windows 10), but all to no avail.

Any thoughts you may have on what seems like a "dual-treatment" of Chinese characters in R Studio are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Today I came across a similar problem - knitting a markdown document with an interactive plot including some Chinese characters. Code runs fine in normal R session, but output was different when knitting a markdown doc, where a data wrangling step resulted in `<U+xxxx>`, messing up subsequent plotting and thus knitting.

```
 df %>%
    filter(str_detect(variable, "皖"))
```

For me, adding the following line in the markdown document worked:

`Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", "Chinese (Simplified)_China.936")`

[Finding all available locales on a machine is not easy](https://superuser.com/questions/166089/where-is-the-list-of-available-windows-locales), it is a deep rabbit hole. As to why different things happen in an R session and when knitting, I suspect it is due to some default setting when the script is evaluated, but that's speculation.

A little digging into what might be happening here:
`knitr::render` uses `%n%` to get network attribute of [a new? global environment](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/utils.R) by using a primitive function `globalenv()`. We can inspect this function following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function), finding `do_globalenv` in R's source code.