# R sample function issue over 10 million values

Tags: r, sample

I found this quirk in R and can't find much evidence for why it occurs. I was trying to recreate a sample as a check and discovered that the `sample` function behaves differently in certain cases. See this example:

```
# Look at the first ten rows of a randomly ordered vector of the first 10 million integers
set.seed(4)
head(sample(1:10000000), 10)
[1] 5858004   89458 2937396 2773749 8135739 2604277 7244055 9060916 9490395  731445

# Select a specified sample of size 10 from this same list
set.seed(4)
sample(1:10000000), size = 10)
[1] 5858004   89458 2937396 2773749 8135739 2604277 7244055 9060916 9490395  731445


# Try the same for sample size 10,000,001
set.seed(4)
head(sample(1:10000001), 10)
[1] 5858004   89458 2937396 2773750 8135740 2604277 7244056 9060917 9490396  731445

set.seed(4)
sample(1:10000001), size = 10)
[1] 5858004   89458 2937397 2773750 8135743 2604278 7244060 9060923 9490404  731445
```

I tested many values up to this 10 million threshold and found that the values matched (though I admit to not testing more than 10 output rows).

Anyone know what's going on here? Is there something significant about this 10 million number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's something special about `1e7`. If you look at the `sample` code, it ends up calling `sample.int`. And as you can see at `?sample`, the default value for the `useHash` argument of `sample.int` is

```
useHash = (!replace && is.null(prob) && size <= n/2 && n > 1e7)
```

That `&& n > 1e7` means when you get above `1e7`, the default preference switches to `useHash = TRUE`. If you want consistency, call `sample.int` directly and specify the the `useHash` value. (`TRUE` is a good choice for memory efficiency, see the argument description at `?sample` for details.)

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. Should have dug more into the documentation. After inspecting the code, I see that when `useHash = TRUE` it calls `sample2` rather than `sample`. I'm still trying to understand what is actually happening here.

Comment: `sample` always calls `sample.int`. `sample.int`, *using `.Internal()`*, will call one of two `sample` implementations written in C, depending on `useHash`. Whenever you see `.Primitive` or `.Internal`, that is R calling C. `sample2` is the memory-efficient implementation using a hash table, `sample` is the more flexible default for small data. [See this question for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14035506/903061), including instructions of how to view that code using `pryr` in Dominic's answer.  I'm not sure how much more you want/need to understand...