# Why does min/max/sum(c(NA, 4, 5), na.rm = "xyz") work while mean() with same inputs doesn't?

Tags: r, conceptual

I would like to understand why sum/min/max functions in R interpret a character string as TRUE when supplied to na.rm, while `mean()` does not.

My uneducated guess is that `as.logical("xyz")` returns NA, which is being supplied to na.rm as the argument, which for some strange reason is accepted as TRUE for sum/min/max while it isn't for `mean()`

The expected output for `sum(c(NA, 4, 5), na.rm = "xyz")` is an argument is not interpretable as logical error (returned from a mean). I don't understand why that isn't the case.

Comment: It is not a coincidence that `min/max/sum` are primitives while `mean` is not.  The processing of `if (na.rm)` produces an error in `mean.default`, and I assume it does not in `min/max/sum` due to their being primitives.

Comment: This QA is very similar, and points in the right direction of examining the C source code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035586/

Comment: e.g. https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/1abc6ab6842af405b4b51da4a3422fd5a5153f9a/src/main/summary.c#L442-L448

Comment: I agree that it would useful if `na.rm` would be evaluated & coerced consistently across the board. Note that `na.rm="FALSE"` is indeed parsed as a logical, so it's not that any string becomes TRUE, cf. `sum(c(1:3,NA), na.rm="xyz") == 6`, `sum(c(1:3,NA), na.rm="TRUE") == 6`, and `sum(c(1:3,NA), na.rm="FALSE") == NA`.

Comment: Agreed! I don't understand the need for inconsistency here. I am not familiar with C but I would assume some of sort of strict type check should be simple to implement and would enforce consistent behavior across the board. Was definitely a [WAT!?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) moment for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as `mean` is concerned it is quite straightforward. As @Rich Scriven mentions if you type `mean.default` in the console you see a section of code

```
if (na.rm) 
   x <- x[!is.na(x)]
```

which gives you the error.

```
mean(1:10, na.rm = "abc") #gives
```

> Error in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] : 
>     argument is not interpretable as logical

which is similar to doing

```
if ("abc") "Hello"
```

> Error in if ("abc") "Hello" : argument is not interpretable as logical

---

Now regarding `sum`, `min`, `max` and other primitive functions which is implemented in C. The source code of these functions is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/summary.c). There is a parameter `Rboolean narm` passed into the function.

The way C treats boolean is different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
  bool a = "abc";
  if (a)
    printf("Hello World");
  else
    printf("Not Hello World");
  return 0;
}
```

If you run the above `C` code it will print "Hello World". Run the demo [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/B1OYjSzTE). If you pass a string input to boolean type it is considered as `TRUE` in `C`. In fact that is even true with numbers as well

```
sum(1:10, na.rm = 12)
```

works as well.

PS - I am no expert in C and know a little bit of R. Finding all these insights took lot of time. Let me know if I have misinterpreted something and provided any false information.

Comment: Thanks! I guess character strings and numbers are considered truthy in C but it still perturbs me that the implementation is not consistent with R's rules. I wonder if there is a reason why these primitives haven't been refactored for consistency (with some sort of type check in C).

Comment: @Puzhu I agree. It would have been much better if these functions showed consistent behavior irrespective of their underlying implementation.