# How to see underlying code for a function written in c in R?

Tags: r

When an R function is typed *without* `()`, the code that makes up the function will be returned

e.g.

```
head
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("head")
<bytecode: 0x0000022cd79ce9a8>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

How can I do this for a function that is calling some C code?

#### Example

I am trying to see the (c) code that makes up the `_pdftools_poppler_pdf_text` function from `pdftools` package (which can be found by running `pdftools:::poppler_pdf_text`, which itself comes from the exported function `pdf_text`)

i.e.

```
pdftools:::poppler_pdf_text
```

Returns

```
function (x, opw, upw) 
{
    .Call("_pdftools_poppler_pdf_text", PACKAGE = "pdftools", 
        x, opw, upw)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000022ce8bff450>
<environment: namespace:pdftools>
```

How can I see the (c) code that makes up `_pdftools_poppler_pdf_text` ?

Comment: ```pryr::show_c_source(...)```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function