# What powers the ellipsis (three-dots) feature in R?

Tags: r

Many questions have been asked about how to use ... in R. However, I have not seen a good explanation of how it works under the hood. **How is ... implemented?** I'm just looking for a high level overview.

The ... feature is highly useful, but it seems to be a black box for a lot of people. I think understanding what makes it work would go a long way towards demystifying the concept.

Comment: This is my first question on Stack Overflow. If you think it needs improvement, please give me feedback and I'll edit the question!

Comment: A strongly related question is [How to see the source code of R .Internal or .Primitive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14035506/903061), though it's not a dupe because it's certainly nontrivial to go from those answers to finding where in the parser code `...` is managed.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks. I'm think a high level overview could still be helpful, even if it doesn't go into the nitty-gritty of the internal R C code.

Answer (score 2):

When a function is called, R goes through a process of matching the arguments the caller used to formal arguments for the function.  The `match.call` function in R duplicates this process.  So for example,

```r
f <- function(x = 1, y, ...) {
  match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
}

f(2)
#> f(x = 2)
f(y = 3)
#> f(y = 3)
f(z = 4)
#> f(... = pairlist(z = 4))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

You can see that `z`, which is not a formal argument, gets caught up in the `...` argument, which is internally a "pairlist".  You can use the `...` argument in
other calls; if `f()` had

```
g(...)
```

in its body, then `f(z = 4)` would end up calling `g(z = 4)`, because the pairlist of arguments would be substituted for the `...` in the call.  This is commonly used in the form `list(...)` to turn `...` into a regular vector list:  it calls the `list()` function with arguments from the pairlist.

There are a few special constructions for working with `...`:  see the `?"..."` help page for details.

Comment: So ... takes all caller-defined arguments that are not formal arguments, and captures them as a pairlist? Thank you, I think the concept of a pairlist is the key here.

Comment: Pairlists act very much like regular lists, but the implementation is different:  pairlists are linked lists (so adding and removing entries is really quick), while regular lists are vectors (so accessing entries by index is quick).  I imagine the call starts as a pairlist, and args are pulled out of it as they are matched to formal arguments; the `...` pairlist is what is left at the end.

Comment: Partial match of argument name can often lead to strange behavior :-) see for ex `test=function(xx=1,...) { print(xx); print(list(...)) }` which when called with `test(x=3)` will print `3` and `list()` instead of `1` and `list(c=3)` as expected !

Comment: Your expectations don't match the documented behaviour.  Yes, it's strange, but it shouldn't be a surprise.