# what is the best code to write this conditional rowwise function in a tibble?

Tags: r, function, tibble, rowwise

I want to calculate the geometrical mean of two vectors in a tibble using the tidyverse. The calculated mean should be done *rowwise* for the two variables. I wrote the function below to this end, and it worked, but I am just wondering how could this operation be done or written in a more efficient way of coding, with more efficient I mean less code, faster and neater. Any better ideas? Just thinking loud, can `map_*()` be implemented in this case? I am also aware of using `rowwise()` but as far as I know lately the author of the tidyverse Hadley Wickham downplayed the use of `rowwise()` strategically.

A minimal representative example is below:

**Reprex**

```
df <- tribble(
    ~v1, ~ v2,
    4, 5,
    NA, 7,
    2, 2,
    3, NA,
    NA, NA,
    9, 9)
```

**Suggested function**

```
gMean <- function (df, v1, v2){
    output <- vector ("double", nrow (df))
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
        output[[i]] <- case_when (!is.na(df$v1[i]) && !is.na(df$v2[i]) ~ ((df$v1[i] * df$v2[i]) ^ 0.5), 
                                  is.na (df$v1[i]) && is.na (df$v2[i]) ~ 1, 
                                  !is.na(df$v1[i]) && is.na(df$v2[i]) ~ df$v1[i], 
                                  is.na(df$v1[i]) && !is.na(df$v2[i]) ~ df$v2[i]
                                  )
    }
    output
}
```

**output**

```
df %>%
    gMean (v1, v2)

[1] 4.472136 7.000000 2.000000 3.000000 1.000000 9.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also (just) use `mutate` instead of looping over each row.

In your case, there is no need to `map` or to use `rowwise`, and as `case_when` is evaluating from the bottom and up, you can simplify your `is.na` calls as well.

```r
df |> mutate(gMean = case_when(is.na(v1) & is.na(v2) ~ 1,
                               is.na(v1) ~ v2,
                               is.na(v2) ~ v1,
                               TRUE ~ sqrt(v1 * v2)))
```

However, if we want to use `rowwise()` or `map2_dbl()` we could use `prod` to allow for an `na.rm`-option, and only take the square root (`^(1/2)`), where  2 values are available. Utilizing that `1/0` is defined as `Inf` in R, and `1^Inf` as `1`.

```
df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(gMean = prod(v1, v2, na.rm = TRUE) ^ (1 / sum(c(!is.na(v1), !is.na(v2))))) |>
  ungroup()
```

```r
df |>
  mutate(gMean = map2_dbl(v1, v2, ~ prod(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE) ^ (1 / sum(c(!is.na(.x), !is.na(.y))))))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     v1    v2 gMean
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     5  4.47
2    NA     7  7   
3     2     2  2   
4     3    NA  3   
5    NA    NA  1   
6     9     9  9
```

Comment: Took me few seconds to indeed realize that your solution without rowwise would work.  Still occasionally tripping over when and when not to use `rowwise()`.

Comment: and if you want to achieve your expected output above, just add a `pull(gMean)`

Comment: the `base::prod()` how could you view its source code in R?

Comment: It's a primitive function so you'll need to dig into the source code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function

Comment: `1 ^ Inf = 1` is great and brilliantly exploited by your code `prod(v1, v2, na.rm = TRUE) ^ (1 / sum(c(!is.na(v1), !is.na(v2))))`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(gMean = map2_dbl(v1, v2, ~ sqrt(.x * .y)) %>% 
           coalesce(v1, v2) %>% if_else(is.na(.), 1, .))

#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      v1    v2 gMean
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     5  4.47
#> 2    NA     7  7   
#> 3     2     2  2   
#> 4     3    NA  3   
#> 5    NA    NA  1   
#> 6     9     9  9
```

Comment: thanks, but strangely enough when I run your nifty code I get a geometrical mean for the first row (4 * 5) = `4` but when I run `sqrt(4 * 5)` I get it right `4.47`. Any idea why?

Comment: Oh, I saw your edit, now it works.