# C_qf function - base stats packages

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I have been running a piece of code which uses the gamlss `qEGB2()` function. However, it has been producing the following warning message:

```
In qf(p, 2 * nu, 2 * tau) : full precision may not have been achieved in 'qbeta'
```

When stepping into the qf function (within the qEGB2 function), the source code is as follows:

```
function (p, df1, df2, ncp, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .Call(C_qf, p, df1, df2, lower.tail, log.p)
    else .Call(C_qnf, p, df1, df2, ncp, lower.tail, log.p)
}
```

I wanted to see the source code of the qf function to get an idea of how qbeta is used and why it is not achieving full precision. If this is due to a number of iterations, I was considering manually copying the code across and seeing if increasing iterations would allow convergence.

When trying to step into the C_qf function I get the following output:

```
list("qf", <pointer: 0x0000024bef45d710>, list("stats", "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll", 
  FALSE, <pointer: 0x0000000071100000>, <pointer: 0x0000024bef4041e0>), 
  5L)
```

I have followed the file path and opened (but not edited) the .dll file but this just produces  a document full of symbols which I don't think are meant for human eyes!

Is there any other way I can access the source code for the C_qf function?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see the source code of R .Internal or .Primitive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function) - in particular Winston Chang's r-source GitHub mirror has `qf.c` [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/qf.c).

Answer (score 1):

The functions `qf` and `qbeta` are related as follows:

```r
qf(0.8, df1 = 3, df2 = 5)
# 2.253017

u <- qbeta(0.8, shape1 = 3/2, shape2 = 5/2)
5/3 * u / (1 - u) 
# 2.253017
```

The warning you get is due to a too large value of `df1` or `df2`.

Comment: So I saw a comment in the C source code Sam provided which noted qbeta does not do well with extreme cases. Both my DoF parameters are less than one so I don't think they are too large. Could the qbeta function also struggle with too low DoF parameters? If so, is there any workaround to calculate the EGB2 quantiles?

Comment: @user928670 Ah ok. What is EGB2?

Comment: And what are the values of your parameters?